# Appending CSV rows to dictionary is only allowing a certain amount of items to dictionary

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I'm creating a dictionary from a csv file that contains about 14k rows.
Appending the rows to an array works find it appends all rows.
But when I am trying to append to a dictionary, which I want, it is only appending 55 items. And I am not sure why this is happening. Locations are strings and numbers are string integers.

```
import csv

dictionary = {} #Length of dictionary is only 55
location = [] #Length of location and number is 13,792
number = []

with open('C:/Users/././.csv') as c:
    csvReader = csv.reader(c, delimiter=',')
    for row in csvReader:
        location.append(row[3])
        number.append(row[11])
        dictionary[row[3]] = row[11]
```

Answer (score 1):

Dict keys are unique, and by assigning a new value to an existing key it overwrites the previous value of the key. Since you most likely have only 55 unique locations and multiple numbers per location, you can use a dict of lists as a data structure instead:

```
for row in csvReader:
    dictionary.setdefault(row[3], []).append(row[11])
```

Answer (score 0):

The keys of dictionaries must be unique. Therefore, the most likely reason is that you have duplicate values in `locations`.

To test this, use `print(len(set(location)))`. I suspect it will print `55`.